# CakePHP CakeSchema question

Tags: cakephp, migration

If there any manual or article on how use CakeShema?
I'm interested in using models & using bare sql in before() and after() methods.

Comment: There's very little documentation on it and personally, in use I have found the Schema shell to be very unstable and buggy. It simply fails to work with particular model/db setups, sometimes only later on after you have already established a number of snapshots. This is up to and including version 1.2.5. I wouldn't recommend using it there. :(

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same for the current CakePHP v1.2.6